# How To Put Google Adsense Ads for testing?

Tags: html, adsense

Currently, we are working on our final year project and want to use Google ads to gain some more marks .

While the website is still in development, we want to test where and how to use ads in the UI. In short, we wish to try Adsense ads, But how can I test Ads without approval?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to see how and where Adsense ad is placed on your website is to sign up for Google Adsense. After you have been approved you can add your website and via the preview function you can see where adsense automatically places ads on your websites.

Here you can also indicate whether or not you want to show ads in this position. Adsense auto-ads will learn from your feedback.

If you want to keep control over the places where you display advertisements, it is best to disable auto ads and manually add ads in the location of your choice. Keep in mind the guidelines of Google Adsense.